# Pie Menu in 2.77?

Tags: interface, pie-menu

I'm running Blender 2.77 on OS X.
I'm following a book that was written I believe for 2.72, and they mention a 'Pie Menu' add on that can be enabled in the UI area of Add Ons in User Preferences. Nothing's listed there, and pressing 'Q' does nothing in 3D view. Am I missing something? Did they abandon this, or is it hidden somewhere? Strangely I can find no documentation on a pie menu in 2.77.

The author seemed enthusiastic about this becoming a default feature in future versions.

Comment: It should be there, it's there for me in 2.77a

Comment: Not seeing it... User Interface in Add-Ons is completely empty. I'm going to try to reinstall Blender, maybe it got lost somehow...

Comment: Are you installing the official build from blender.org?

For me it's in the "community" section. Have you enabled that under "Supported Level" beneath the search bar?

Comment: After downloading Blender again, and replacing the .app, I see it now. Not sure what happened there - but that seemed to have done it. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

Deleted the .app in Applications, and downloaded Blender 2.77 again. Not sure what happened there, but I see the option now.